# Intermittent E_NOINTERFACE Error From C#/VB.Net DLLs Connecting to C++ ActiveX Exe

Tags: .net, com, activex, com-interop

I am trying to figure why this error is happening and determine if it is possible to prevent it.

So, this is all in VS2008 running on Windows XP Pro SP3. I am writing plugin toolbar DLLs for a mapping application called FalconView 4.1.1.6. FalconView (fvw.exe) is an activex application.  The toolbars generally work fine except for an occasional pain in the neck error (the error message I am getting is at the end of this question since it is pretty long).

I can sometimes force this error message by installing a release version of our software on a test laptop, replacing the release DLL with the debug DLL (for test purposes), uninstalling the toolbar, and then installing the next version of the toolbar.  Boom, there is the error. The error also happens when writing and debugging as well but less predictably.  I can fix this on my development machine by removing references to fvw from the project, exiting vs2008, un-registering all copies of Interop.fvw.dll (generated from a tlb file provided by FalconView), running "fvw /regserver", reloading the project, and adding Interop.fvw.dll back into the project.  What a pain! What is happening here? Is there a way to prevent this?

Thanks!

The error in question:
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'fvw.MapClass' to interface type 'fvw.IMap'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{E353BC6C-E8AB-11D3-80B9-00C04F60B086}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeDispMethod(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Object target, Object[] args, Boolean[] byrefModifiers, Int32 culture, String[] namedParameters)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
   at fvw.MapClass.GetElevation(Double lat, Double lon, Int32& elevation)
   at Toolbar.rpuav_com.SendElevationData(Hub Station)

Note that {E353BC6C-E8AB-11D3-80B9-00C04F60B086} is in the registry when I look for it.

Comment: There's something missing, a plugin host usually requires you telling it where to look for the plugin.  Not uncommonly done by selecting your plugin in an Options dialog.  In which case the problem is caused by the GUID of your plugin changing.  You can apply the [Guid] attribute to your ComVisible interface to nail it down and avoid having the CLR auto-generate one.  This does invoke DLL Hell, remove it again when you're done testing.

Comment: @HansPassant You are right about having to add the plugin to the host.  This is done via a registry entry that is made at installation. I like the sound of your GUID idea as it sounds very plausible for this situation.  Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uggg... I was really hoping that I wouldn't end up answering my own question. It feels so wrong somehow.

Anyhow, the problem was with the Interop.fvw.dll file being used.  We are supposed to use the one provided with FalconView (built with the also-provided fvw.tlb). Our project references that dll and Visual Studio copies it to our release folder when building the Release version of our plugin and to the Program Files folder when we are debugging.  Somehow, and I don't understand this, a new Interop.fvw.dll gets generated (possibly an intern, other employee, or just magic??) and the bloody thing gets "stuck" in the problem projects.

How can I tell a new interop dll is re-generated?  The public key token is all zeros while the one from the FalconView makers has an actual number.  Now if only they would sign their assembly as well.

The fix for me is:

1. remove the offending Interop.fvw.dll from the project references
2. save the project and exit visual studio
3. in the project's Program Files folder run "regasm /u Interop.fvw.dll"
4. run "fvw /regserver" for good measure
5. reload the project and re-reference the proper FalconView Interop.fvw.dll
6. clean the project build and then rebuild

Thanks everyone for the effort at helping!  Very much appreciated!

Comment: "the project's Program Files". what is this referring to?

Comment: Actually this is "the project's Program Files folder". The location where the plugin was installed. In our case we install to a folder in "Program Files" (i.e. C:\Program Files\MyCompany\MyPlugin). We install the Interop.fvw.dll with the plugin and in some newer versions of our toolbar the dll was getting registered which it shouldn't have been.

Answer (score 1):

> I can sometimes force this error message by installing a release
>   version of our software on a test laptop, replacing the release DLL
>   with the debug DLL (for test purposes), uninstalling the toolbar, and
>   then installing the next version of the toolbar. Boom, there is the
>   error.

The GUIDs that the type library exporter (and Visual Studio) generate for the type library ID and class IDs use the assembly version as part of the hash. Therefore, if your assembly version changes (even if it is just the build or revision number) will cause these GUIDs to change. You definitely have to watch out for this if your `AssemblyVersionAttribute` is set to an auto-generated version number (like 1.0.*).

To avoid this problem, either set your assembly to have a static version number or specify your own GUIDs using the `[Guid]` attribute on your classes and interfaces.

Comment: I think this is possible.  We do use static version numbers but there are rare occasions where someone will increment the revision number during testing. If we then took that debug dll and tested it on our test laptop that was expecting a prior version number I could see where that may cause trouble.  The type library for FalconView (the fvw.tlb file) never changes though no does the host app itself.  I need to play with this some I think.  Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

Something is throwing/returning `E_NOINTERFACE`, supposedly because requested interface is not implemented. Typically, it takes place when you `QueryInterface` from an object which is not `NULL` but which does not implement the interface. That is, it's completely applciation specific and is unlikely to be related to registry settings. As it's your app, you can debug and see what exactly you are querying for `fvw.IMap` and why it does not expose the interface in question.

Comment: Yeah, really strange.  Another developer claimed this happened spontaneously while the application and plugin were running.  All was well and then... boom! The E_NOINTERFACE error appeared in the running log. I am taking that report with a grain of salt though... sounds implausible.  What you say could fit here because to fix the problem I have to at the very least run "fvw.exe /REGSERVER" to get things up and going again.  Something causes fvw.exe to unregister somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say that the E_NOINTERFACE error came from attempting to marshal the object from one thread to another.

Check to ensure that a proxy/stub DLL is registered for the interface you're trying to marshal.

Comment: The plugin I am working on is some seriously legacy code with lots of cross-thread calls.  I am going to keep this idea in mind. Thanks!

Comment: Wow! A little Google research on what Larry Osterman said, not that I even doubted him, showed that it is possible for two or more threads to call the same object almost simultaneously ultimately leading to exactly this error message. I don't think it applies here though as our toolbars all work the same way and this problem is pretty rare.